# issue with spring 4 with apache tiles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

Hi I am getting this weired behavior.
I did a poc of apache tiles 3 with spring mvc 4 which seemed to work perfectly fine for me.
But integrating the same in my project i am getting the following error:

```
015-05-19 19:49:16,907 ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:331) - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/media/rmishra/823a23ae-892b-43f0-896e-ecf271f6715a/project/minda/web/web_war/target/web_war-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/services_impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1618) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$241(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/2000090788.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:88) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:65) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:176) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:725) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49) ~[spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49) ~[spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564) ~[spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Following is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>web</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <description>
        web app to be consumed by users
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext-web.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entityManagerFactory</param-name>
            <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CacheControlFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            com.minda.iconnect.web.filter.CacheControlFilter
        </filter-class>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheControlFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

and dipatcher config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/web-resources/**" location="/web-resources/mytheme/" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/views/</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Tiles configuration -->

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.minda.iconnect</groupId>
        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.minda.iconnect.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>web_war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>web_war</name>
    <description>Minda iConnect Web Site War Module</description>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <env.basedir>../../env</env.basedir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <sitemesh.version>3.0-alpha-2</sitemesh.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.minda.iconnect.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>web_services_facade</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.minda.iconnect</groupId>
            <artifactId>web_common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ccavenue</groupId>
            <artifactId>ccavutil</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sitemesh</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>${sitemesh.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

tiles config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="defaultTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/template/default/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/template/default/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you get a stacktrace from hibernate, why to you think tiles is involved?

Comment: @GUIDO I believe tiles is involved as the issue started coming only after i tried to integrate tiles. As soon as I remove the tiles configurations the project starts running fine.

Comment: your stacktrace looks very similar to this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8899 try to see if the suggestions in the comments there help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of digging I was able to figure out the problem and a possible solution.

The problem was due to conflict with a incompatible java 8 library of javassist and tiles.

The solution was to exclude the javassist dependency from tiles using below config

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```